# Using jxls, what is the proper way to wire up an AreaListener?

Tags: jxls

I'm using Java, jxls-poi 2.13.0 to convert some XML data to a xlsm.

This code processes different templates depending on the data.
The area for the jx:each will be different for each template & must be defined in the template.

In some cases, I need to apply a style to all the cells in the range.
I made an AreaListener - but the listener is never called.
What am I doing wrong?

A sample template comment .. the addresses/directions vary.

[image: template comment screenshot]

the code that processes the template (& adds the listener)

[image: code screenshot]

The listener is minimal:

[image: listener screenshot]

This outputs the below. I expected to see lots of output from the listener starting with 'CALLED' but got none.

[image: output screenshot]